Error when using diagnose function from glmmTMB
I'm using glmmTMB (version 1.1.9) to run a step selection analysis with the two-step approach suggested by Muff et al. 2020 (fitting a Poisson model specifying a stratum-specific fixed intercept) specifying in the function call glmmTMB:
map = list(theta=factor(c(NA,1:6))), start = list(theta=c(log(1e3),0,0,0,0,0,0))
When running the diagnose() function I get the error:
"Error in names(pp) <- nn :  'names' attribute [15] must be the same length as the vector [14]"
When looking at the function code of diagnose the issue arises on line 36:
rownames(ss) <- names(pp) <- nn
nn has one parameter more than pp, I'm asuming because of the map-specification of theta=factor(c(NA,1:6)) where the first stratum specific intercept is no estimated but fixed.
Also when running the function line by line I get the error that
"Error in UseMethod("isREML") :  no applicable method for 'isREML' applied to an object of class "glmmTMB"
I can circumvent my issue with:
rownames(ss) <- names(pp) <- nn[!startsWith(names(nn), "theta1")]
(which works in my case) but I was wondering if someting has changed with the newest version of glmmTMB because diagnose used to work before on the same models. I didn't go back to older versions of glmmTMB as I don't have it installed anylonger.
Many thanks for your support

Can you please post an issue with a reproducible example to the glmmTMB issues list ?
